# I am stuck about how can i use sharedpreferences to retain my card view state after I restart the app? Kindly suggest some code if possible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

[image]   [image]

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CardView cardview;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams1;
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        layout=findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

// The button press will add card

```
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cards();
            }
        });
    }
```

// Function to add cardview tiles. This will function will add cardview tile

```
    private void cards()
    {
        cardview = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
        layoutparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutparams1.setMargins(18, 30, 18, 0);
        cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
        cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        cardview.setMinimumHeight(400);
        cardview.setRadius(30);
        layout.addView(cardview);
    }
}
```

// The xml file for the same is mentioned below and containt just a single button within a relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

//---------------------------------------
// UPDATE #2 After implementing the onPause() and onResume method -------------------------------//

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CardView cardview;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams1;
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    public SharedPreferences mSettings;
    int mCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSettings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mCount = 0;

        Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        layout=findViewById(R.id.layout);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCount++;
                cards();
            }
        });
    }

    private void cards()
    {
        cardview = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
        layoutparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutparams1.setMargins(18, 30, 18, 0);
        cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
        cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        cardview.setMinimumHeight(400);
        cardview.setRadius(30);
        layout.addView(cardview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
        editor.putInt("COUNT_CARDS", mCount);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mSettings.contains("COUNT_CARDS")) {
            mCount = mSettings.getInt("COUNT_CARDS", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on mobile so can’t share a code but i will try to give you a solution.

First thing first Shared Preference’s should used to store small bits of data not the whole database.

Override onStop or onPause (depending on your needs) and store whatever data you want to keep.

And then inside onCreate or onResume and retrieve that data from SharedPreferences and add it in your list.

You also have to keep in mind that if you are doing this using onPause (store) and onResume (retrieve) your list is not destroyed so you might end up duplicate with items in your list.

Comment: Is the updated code above similar to what you are trying to say?

Comment: If you needed to store only count then yeah this is good. I think you got the idea. Now depending what you want to store and retrieve can be done with more complex data. If data is small then you can keep using sharedPreferences or you can go with database as well.

Comment: But this updated code will just work if app goes in background and comes back. In case your app is closed then it won’t show you the items in list. For that you can call cards() function multiple times depending what mCount value you get from shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save number of cards you realy can use SharedPrefernces. Something like this:
This is your Acivity class field

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int mCount = 0;
```

Add count to click listener

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mCount++;
                cards();
            }
        });
```

Save count to SharedPreferences in onPause()

```
Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
editor.putInt("COUNT_CARDS", mCount);
editor.apply();
```

Read from SharedPreferences in onResume()

```
if(mSettings.contains("COUNT_CARDS")) {
    mCount = mSettings.getInt("COUNT_CARDS", 0);
}
```

Then add as many cards to your layaout "count" times.
But if you want to save more complex data you should use database. Take a look at [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room)

Comment: I had implemented your code but still, after restarting the app the cards are not showing up. You may have a look above at the updated code.